# Why does getResourceAsStream() and reading file with FileInputStream return arrays of different length?

Tags: java, io

I want to read files as byte arrays and realised that amount of read bytes varies depending on the used method. Here the relevant code:

```
    public byte[] readResource() {
    try (InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(FILE_NAME)) {
        int available = is.available();
        byte[] result = new byte[available];
        is.read(result, 0, available);

        return result;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Failed to load resource '{}'", FILE_NAME, e);
    }

    return new byte[0];
}

public byte[] readFile() {
    File file = new File(FILE_PATH + FILE_NAME);
    try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file)) {
        int available = is.available();
        byte[] result = new byte[available];
        is.read(result, 0, available);

        return result;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Failed to load file '{}'", FILE_NAME, e);
    }

    return new byte[0];
}
```

Calling File.length() and reading with the FileInputStream returns the correct length of 21566 bytes for the given test file, though reading the file as a resources returns 21622 bytes.

Does anyone know why I get different results and how to fix it so that readResource() returns the correct result?

Comment: Maybe zthat are different files?

Comment: You're also not reading bytes correctly. available() doesn't return the length of the file. And read() isn't guaranteed to read the number of bytes you ask it to read. Read the Java IO tutorial to know how to properly read all the bytes of a stream.

Comment: Thanks! That helped. getResourceAsStream() took an old version of that image from the target-folder.

Answer (score 4):

> Why does getResourceAsStream() and reading file with FileInputStream return arrays of different length?

Because you're misusing the `available()` method in a way that is specifically warned *against* in the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available()):

> "It is never correct to use the return value of this method to allocate a buffer intended to hold all data in this stream."

and

> Does anyone know why I get different results and how to fix it so that readResource() returns the correct result?

Read in a loop until end of stream.

Answer (score 3):

According to the the [API docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available()) of InputStream,  `InputStream.available()` does not return the size of the resource - it returns

> an estimate of the number of bytes that can be read (or skipped over) from this input stream without blocking

To get the size of a resource from a stream, you need to fully read the stream, and count the bytes read.

To read the stream and return the contents as a byte array, you could do something like this:

```
    try (   InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(FILE_NAME);
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {

        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead = 0;
        while ((bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            bos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        return bos.toByteArray();

    }
```

Comment: Well he doesn't actually need the size of the resource, he needs its entire contents.